# Comment expliquer la structure « qui va en s’aggravant »

Tags: expressions

> Cette tragédie humaine qui frappe des franges entières de populations africaines, est bel et bien la source principale du problème migratoire **qui va en s’aggravant** d’année en année

Je n’ai jamais repéré une telle tournure (verbe + en + participe présent). Est-elle courante ? Si j’ai bien compris le sens (**qui s’aggravent**). Peut-on donc dire « le problème **qui va en faisant** débat » pour dire « le problème **qui fait** débat »

Answer (score 4):

Cette expression est généralement utilisée avec des verbes de transition comme s'aggravant, s'améliorant, augmentant, diminuant, refroidissant, réchauffant, etc. Avec ces transformations, le verbe "aller" renforce la nuance d'un mouvement progressif avec le temps. Dans ton premier exemple, on peut donc comprendre "qui s'aggrave *progressivement au fil du temps*". Le point important à retenir est qu'on comprends cette nuance même sans "d'année en année".

- [...] problème migratoire qui va en s'aggravant.
- [...] problème migratoire qui va en s’aggravant *d’année en année* (seulement une précision).

Sans l'utilisation d'un verbe de transition, le verbe "aller" devient discutable et est mis en évidence. Dans ton deuxième exemple, on se demande pourquoi avoir préciser le mouvement s'il n'y a pas de changement? L'expression perd donc son autonomie, devient dépendante du contexte et sort de l'usage conventionel:

- Ce problème qui va en faisant débat **de plus en plus** (contexte devient obligatoire, pas naturel)
- Ce problème qui fait débat de plus en plus.

En d'autres mots, cette utilisation est une addition non nécessaire et douteuse sans une évolution claire.

Answer (score 3):

C'est un type de tournure très courant. Le couple *verbe + gérondif* marque la simultanéité d'une action principale et d'une action secondaire qui vient préciser une circonstance. Par exemple :

> Il parle en dormant.
> Il téléphone en conduisant.
> Il s'essouffle en montant les escaliers.

Dans la phrase de la question, *qui va en s'aggravant* combine donc le verbe *aller*, qui signifie ici *évoluer*, et le verbe *aggraver* : Le problème migratoire évolue année après année et cette évolution va dans le mauvais sens.

La phrase « le problème qui va en faisant débat » n'est pas du tout naturelle. Le verbe *aller* est normalement associé à un verbe indiquant une évolution, mais *faire débat* ne correspond pas à ce modèle.

Les gérondifs que l'on trouve le plus souvent associés à *qui va en* sont *augmentant, s'élargissant, s'accentuant, diminuant, montant, croissant, décroissant...*

S'il fallait conserver ce gérondif, on pourrait dire par exemple :

> Le problème qui nous dérange en faisant débat.

Comment: Je pense que tu fais une assimilation trop poussée  entre *en* suivit du gérondif et aller (en) suivit du gérondif.  En grammaire la tournure est traitée avec "aller" (p.e. Grevisse met ça dans *verbes auxiliaires* /aller). Je te signale  [cette thèse](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00872100/document) sur les périphrases verbales  en part. p. 62 : « Le cas d’aller + gérondif ».  Intéressant  de signaler que ce *en* dans  *aller en + gér.* est optionnel (mais dans ce cas tournure bcp + litt.) alors que dans tes premiers exemples avec les compl. de manière il ne peut pas être enlevé.

Comment: @None C'est vrai. Il s'agit d'un cas particulier, *aller* n'est pas 100% interchangeable avec *évoluer*. Je vais tâcher d'ajuster ma réponse quand j'aurai le temps. merci !

Answer (score 2):

Cette construction est idiomatique.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aller)  **b)** Usuel. [La forme en *-ant* est précédée de *en* ; le suj. est gén. un inanimé] Aller en s'accroissant, en diminuant, en augmentant, en (s') élargissant, en (s') affaiblissant, en grandissant

On peut voir que dans la famille des idiomatismes tous les éléments ont la même  caractéristique : ils expriment un changement d'ampleur ou de degré  tout au long d'une progression. Apparemment, l'usage est conçu selon un gradient de spécificité.
On pourrait donc utiliser des alternatives telles que les suivantes.

- en se rapetissant ([réf.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=va+en+se+rapetissant&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cva%20en%20se%20rapetissant%3B%2Cc0)),  en empirant ([réf.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=va+en+empirant&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cva%20en%20empirant%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cva%20en%20empirant%3B%2Cc0)), en s'améliorant ([réf.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=va+en+s%27am%C3%A9liorant&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cva%20en%20s%27am%C3%A9liorant%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cva%20en%20s%27am%C3%A9liorant%3B%2Cc0))

Il est plutôt nécessaire que le changement d'ampleur ou de degré soit exprimé par un terme non spécifique, mais il  y a des exceptions (« en s'affaiblissant » dans la liste du dictionnaire).

- aller en dégénérant ([réf.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=aller+en+d%C3%A9g%C3%A9n%C3%A9rant&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caller%20en%20d%C3%A9g%C3%A9n%C3%A9rant%3B%2Cc0)), aller en dépérissant ([réf.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=all%C3%A9+en+d%C3%A9p%C3%A9rissant&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Call%C3%A9%20en%20d%C3%A9p%C3%A9rissant%3B%2Cc0))
  (*On voit d'après les ngrams que ces constructions particulières ne sont utilisées autant que les autres.*)

On ne trouve pas de cas dans les livres Google pour les cas suivant mais ils peuvent être assimilés

- aller en ralentissant, aller en accélérant,

De ce fait, les possibilités suivantes ne sont pas ressenties comme idiomatiques.

- <s>aller en s'unifiant, aller en (se) gonflant,</s>

Finalement, « aller en faisant débat », qui  n'exprime aucune notion de changement d'ampleur ou de degré, n'est pas idiomatique.